# 404 when displaying background image in CSS with rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, asset-pipeline

I manually added assets/images directory in a rails 3.2 app and added the image background.png . When referring to the image from css

`background: url("assets/background.png") no-repeat;`

I am getting a 404 , however assets/stylesheets and assets/javascripts are showing up.

**UPDATE

it appears as if I revert back to explicitly calling the stylesheet ie

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "home.css"%>
```

instead of

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

The background image reders correctly

Answer (score 3):

That url is relative to where the style sheet is. You probably want either `url(../assets/background.png)` to go up a level from your style sheet or `url(/assets/background.png)` to go from the root.

Comment: I changed `background: url("assets/background.png") no-repeat;` to `background: url(image_url("background.png")) no-repeat;` which renders /assets/background.png . Also `url(../assets/background.png)` renders /assets/background.png also , however it still returning a 404

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
url(<%= asset_path 'background.png' %>)
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: still is throwing me in the same directory as above solution

Comment: 1. did you restart your app after adding a folder?
2. did you check the characters case? maybe you've got a *.PNG file, not the *.png.